# Ethereum - Embark console method calls all returning as undefined

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, embark

I'm using the Embark framework to build my first DApp, and have been successful in building the "SimpleStorage" Embark demo shown [here](https://ethereumdev.io/getting-started-with-embark-framework/). I can use the web interface to set and retrieve values successfully, but when I try to do so directly from the Embark console, it returns `undefined` for any method call to any contract I've deployed.

[image]

I've tried using Go-Ethereum as well as EthereumJS TestRPC to no avail.

I also reported the issue [here](https://github.com/embark-framework/embark/issues/317) where people seem to have had the same problem but the issue has already been closed by the projects maintainer.

Comment: This should probably be moved to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embark uses [web3.js 1.0](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) , it should be `MDBAccount.methods.post("Hello World").send()` and `MDBService.methods.register().send({gas:900000})` The complete documentation can be found [here](https://embark.status.im/docs/).